# .sh execution asking for "how you want to open this file" , not executing in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, apache-kafka, sh, execution

I have downloaded kafka and trying to execute the start script using

```
.\bin\kafka-server-start.sh
.\config\server.properties
```

in cmd prompt, but the script is not executing ,instead windows is throwing "How do you want to open this .sh file".

The current default in "Set Assosiations" is "unknown application", not able to figure out why it is not executed.

Comment: Are you sure that this is intended to work? `.sh` files usually are used under *nix, while you should use some `.bat` on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka has seperate batch files for windows environment in `<kafka dir>/bin/windows` directory. Use those to run on windows environment like this.

Use `kafka-server-start.bat` and `kafka-server-stop.bat` for kafka cluster.

You can find more details. https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/bin/windows

Comment: This was a big help, i missed to see that. However when i am executing bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties getting error "the syntax of the command is not correct . the input line is too long"

Comment: There could be several reason like having a long CLASSPATH. Can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: It is working now. i reduced the long folder name to few letters , like kafka_2.11-2.1.0 to 'kafka' and it is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are Windows versions of all the scripts in the `bin/windows` directory, see https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/bin/windows.

When running on Windows, use those instead of the normal shell scripts. This is mentioned literally in the first line of the [Quick Start](http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) section in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It helped.